# Why can't I reduce the screen luminosity on Toshiba L775?

Tags: screen, brightness

I've installed Ubuntu on my Toshiba Satellite L775 but the biggest problem is that I can't reduce the screen luminosity, It's too too bright and I almost can't use it at night.

Answer (score 0):

That seems strange... I own a Toshiba Satellite P755, and can change the brightness under both the computer settings and the keyboard short-cut (<kbd>FN</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd>). You should (theoretically) be able to change it either way. Have you tried both the short-cut and adjusting the brightness under "Brightness and Lock" under "System Settings?"

Comment: the keyboard short-cut (FN F6 and F7) show the contrast icone and the loading bar but nothing happens.

Comment: My assumption would be that the shortcuts are configured for Windows. Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Also, have you tried adjusting the brightness under System Settings?

Comment: Well yes, in Windows, the keyboard short-cut (FN F6 and F7) work well, I've tried lot of Ubuntu version (11, 12...) but nothing... the screen is toooo bright.